# C# On keypress - exit program

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, exit

My program opens a series of forms all over the screen, am I able to code in an escape method, so on typing of the word "test" the program will close?

I was looking at the msdn keypress and how they use a switch, would I use something similar to check for the pressed key and if the correct key is pressed, a counter will increment of the correct key presses until, for "test", 4 will be reached, and if the pressed key is incorrect reset the counter and start over until the right order of keys are entered.

I hope that makes sense :P

```
public partial class TrollFrm : Form
{
    int number = 1; //change to 2 and have the first instance of troll count = number - 1

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public TrollFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Text = "Trololol - Troll Count: " + number;

        startTimer();

    }

    private void TrollFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //this.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void TrollFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    public void startTimer()
    {
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(createForm);

        //myTimer.Interval = 500;

        myTimer.Start();

    }

    public void createForm(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        Form frm = new TrollChildFrm();

        Random randomX = new Random();

        Random randomY = new Random();

        frm.Text = "Trololol - Troll Count: " + number;

        int xValue;

        int yValue;

        number++;

        if (number % 2 == 0)    //number is even.
        {
            xValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomX.Next(1, 1920))) + 200;

            yValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomY.Next(1, 1080))) - 200;
        }

        else    //number is not even.
        {
            xValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomX.Next(1, 1920))) - 200;

            yValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomY.Next(1, 1080))) + 200;
        }

        frm.Show();

        frm.Location = new Point(xValue, yValue);

        if (number == 20)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: added the code i have so far, not sure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an implementation you could use for scenario you described (not tested though):

```
int exitKeysCount = 0;
private void TrollFrm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (exitKeysCount == 0 && e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
        exitKeysCount = 1;
    else if (exitKeysCount == 1 && e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        exitKeysCount = 2;
    else if (exitKeysCount == 2 && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        exitKeysCount = 3;
    else if (exitKeysCount == 3 && e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
        this.Close();
    else exitKeysCount = 0;
}
```

I assumed TrollFrm is your parent form, if they are all invoked somewhere else replace this.Close() with some function in main program function, also TrollFrm needs focus during key presses.

Comment: No offense but I Thinks Jonathan's Answer is better because it has an else part where you just have added it later on

Comment: still before his answer but it's your call

Comment: Yeh, the first instance is TrollFrm followed by TrollChildFrm's, though I may just be able to use all TrollFrm's now :P Is there a using directive I need to use KeyCode? I was reading the keydown msdn and I seem to have it all but I can't use it...

Comment: also can I make TrollFrm always have focus? At the moment every time a child is created the last child has focus :P

Comment: System.Windows.Forms is the namespace of Keys, you could try to call sth like this.Parent.Focus() in child onload event (or one of those raised when form is shown, don't remember them) or in child forms call parent's TrollFrm_KeyDown in KeyDown event handlers (make it internal instead of private)

Comment: Yeah i have using System.Windows.Forms; but KeyCode still isn't recognised :( (I know it's just something I'm doing wrong I just can't see it :P)

Comment: there should be KeyEventArgs instead of KeyEventHandler: private void TrollFrm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) but I suppose you already noticed that, also if you are using KeyPress instead of KeyDown or KeyUp there will be KeyChar (it is a standard char so compare it like == 't') instead of KeyCode

Answer (score 0):

try this parent on your parent form.

```
 int trollCount = 0;

 private void TrollFrm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventHandler e)
 {
     if (trollCount == 0 && e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
       {
            trollCount = 1;
            frm.Text = "Trololol - Troll Count:" + trollCount
       }
     else if (trollCount == 1 && e.KeyCode== Keys.E)
       {
            trollCount = 2;
            frm.Text = "Trololol - Troll Count:" + trollCount
       }
     else if (trollCount == 2 && e.KeyCode== Keys.S)
       {
            trollCount = 3;
            frm.Text = "Trololol - Troll Count:" + trollCount
       }
     else if (trollCount == 4 && e.KeyCode== Keys.T)
       {
            trollCount = 4;
            this.Close();
       }
     else
        trollCount = 0;
```

tell me if you need anything else.